# Is there any way I can translate the default language to Portuguese?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated some CRUD interface to manage my tables. I put validations in the models. But the returns error messages in English. I would like to return this message in Portuguese because my client is in Brazil. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your config/application.rb probably in line #34 you have commented out

```
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

You should have this:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :pt # if pt means Portugese, I'm not sure now...
```

You would probably need to put some translations in config/locales/pt.yml. More about translating your Rails app you will find in [Rails Guides i18n section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Now, is appearing on my screen:

Name translation missing: pt.activerecord.errors.models.workflow.attributes.name.blank

Do I have to download any package with the language?

Comment: You must populate config/locales/pt.yml with your custom translations. Read the Guides :)

Comment: Tks. Worked Perfectly. I get the dictionary in  https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/pt-BR.yml . ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look in the internationalization guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html